Get the monitor number that the mouse is in?
For some time now, I have been using the function, GetMonitorIndexFromWindow() by shinywong, to get the monitor number, the window is inside of, its very reliable.
GetMonitorIndexFromWindow(windowHandle)
{
    ; Starts with 1.
    monitorIndex := 1

    VarSetCapacity(monitorInfo, 40)
    NumPut(40, monitorInfo)
    
    if (monitorHandle := DllCall("MonitorFromWindow", "uint", windowHandle, "uint", 0x2)) 
        && DllCall("GetMonitorInfo", "uint", monitorHandle, "uint", &monitorInfo) 
    {
        monitorLeft   := NumGet(monitorInfo,  4, "Int")
        monitorTop    := NumGet(monitorInfo,  8, "Int")
        monitorRight  := NumGet(monitorInfo, 12, "Int")
        monitorBottom := NumGet(monitorInfo, 16, "Int")
        workLeft      := NumGet(monitorInfo, 20, "Int")
        workTop       := NumGet(monitorInfo, 24, "Int")
        workRight     := NumGet(monitorInfo, 28, "Int")
        workBottom    := NumGet(monitorInfo, 32, "Int")
        isPrimary     := NumGet(monitorInfo, 36, "Int") & 1

        SysGet, monitorCount, MonitorCount

        Loop, %monitorCount%
        {
            SysGet, tempMon, Monitor, %A_Index%

            ; Compare location to determine the monitor index.
            if ((monitorLeft = tempMonLeft) and (monitorTop = tempMonTop)
                and (monitorRight = tempMonRight) and (monitorBottom = tempMonBottom))
            {
                monitorIndex := A_Index
                break
            }
        }
    }
    
    return %monitorIndex%
}

Today, I am in need of a method for getting the monitor number of the monitor the mouse pointer is inside of. I have looked around and have not found anything useful.
The closest I have managed to get is MDMF_FromPoint() by just me, I say close because, when I use this function it returns a monitor handle:
msgBox,% MDMF_FromPoint() ;prints ---> 1093800931

MDMF_FromPoint(X := "", Y := "") {
    VarSetCapacity(PT, 8, 0)
    If (X = "") || (Y = "") {
        DllCall("User32.dll\GetCursorPos", "Ptr", &PT)
        If (X = "")
            X := NumGet(PT, 0, "Int")
        If (Y = "")
            Y := NumGet(PT, 4, "Int")
    }
    Return DllCall("User32.dll\MonitorFromPoint", "Int64", (X & 0xFFFFFFFF) | (Y << 32), "UInt", 0, "UPtr")
}

If someone could share with me how to convert a monitor handle to a monitor number, I would really appreciate it

Does this help?

Yes that helped, I looked at that thread too but only page 1 of it. Then answer I needed was on page 2. Perhaps propose it as an answer, so I can accept it. Cheers!
